# JavaScript Input Image Comparison

Tags: javascript, laravel

How can I compare an image input to an image stored in my public folder in JavaScript?

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#pic')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(600)
                    .height(600);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    function matching(input){

            if ($('src',e.target.result)=="public_coffee.jpg") {
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "public_coffee.jpg");
                x.setAttribute("width", "304");
                x.setAttribute("height", "228");
                document.body.appendChild(x);
                exit();
            }

    }
```

I am very new to JavaScript. The first function allows me to upload and view an image and it works. The second function should compare the uploaded image with an image in my public folder and then display that image. This second function does not work. What am I doing wrong or not seeing? Could you guys help me out?

Comment: can you define "does not work"?

Comment: I get no errors at all. My button clicks but that's it. No reload, no page updates, nothing.

Comment: there's no button present in the code sample you pasted above. can you come up with a [minimal code sample needed to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Oh my button link is inside my html page, it is <button onclick="matching()">Check</button>